# Recommended way to do the search and populating the grid in ASP.NET Core MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am creating a project where I need to create a view with search textboxes and  a dropdown which would be populated from the server.  Same view also have a grid which would be populated based on the search criteria enter/selected by user.
I want to know what would be the design of the page in terms of showing both on same page.  Should I create a partial view for the grid or Search panel or add both in the single view?
Note that dropdown list would need to be populated from the ViewModel.  So what is the common practice in the situation.  I am new to this I have done few pages but with lot of code, session and ViewBags and I think I am not following recommended practice.

Comment: Unfortunately there are a couple of questions here (Needs more focus). Asking for an opinion is also off-topic here. If you want somebody to review your code then check out [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the design for your web application is according to your requirement.

For example, if you want grid to work with other datasource or view, you could build it as a component, then if you want to use it, you could directly use this component to avoid write the same codes for multiple time.

If you want to use same grid to show in some other page, you could build it a partial view, then you could directly call this view to show something.